# What are all of these questions about Sign Languages?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

As you can see 11 questions were bumped to the front page about Sign Languages.

I changed the tags from [signed-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signed-languages) to  [sign-languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sign-languages) since this is the most common and used way to refer to these languages.

I suggested the former as a tag synonym. Those of you who have an answer score of 3 or higher on that tag, please vote on it. It requires 4 votes to be approved.

Thanks for your attention!